# Sending/Receiving CoAP Requests In Cloud (or Azure IoT HUB)

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, coap

I need to implement CoAP (Constrained Application Protocol) in Cloud for IoT devices.

**I have below questions:**

1. Any good & fast tutorials for CoAP client & server?
2. How to receive CoAP request on my server?
3. Whats the best language for implementing this? Currently my server runs PHP code.
4. And software/website that can help me testing CoAP request, just like "POSTMAN"?
5. How can i implement CoAP in Azure IoT HUB?

And **below are the technologies available to me:**

1. Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines.
2. Microsoft Azure IoT HUB.

***Please guide me, Consider me as a beginner in CoAP***.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check [Microsoft Azure IoT Protocol Gateway](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-protocol-gateway/blob/master/docs/DeveloperGuide.md).

Answer (score 0):

For question #5 - you can use the Azure IoT Gateway as a translation layer between CoAP and one of the protocols that IoT Hub supports.
Take a look at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-windows-gateway-sdk-get-started
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-gateway-kit-c-get-started