# I want to integrate CoAP with the Azure with IoT hub. Below are the available services a) Event hub b) function appsc) Cumulocity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, coap

I want to know whether CoAP is supported by Azure Event Hub. If not, Please help with an architecture which support CoAP without IoT hub.

I have designed that CoAP will be ingestes Event hub and then Function apps and to Cumulocity. Not sure whether it will work in Real time. This is M2M architecture.

Comment: AFAIK, Azure Event Hub does not support CoAP protocol. However, you can use Azure IoT Hub to ingest CoAP messages. You can use Azure Functions to process the messages and then send them to Cumulocity. You can also use Azure Event Hub to ingest the CoAP messages and then use Azure Functions to process the messages and send them to Cumulocity.  [Supporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/on-net/azure-event-hubs-supported-protocols) [Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-exchange-events-different-protocols).

Comment: Thankyou Sampath, But Azure IoT HUB also doesn't support the CoAP protocol right ?

Comment: Refer this [So](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171578/sending-receiving-coap-requests-in-cloud-or-azure-iot-hub)

Comment: Idea is to ingest the CoAP messages in the form of YAML to Azure Event Hub and then translate CoAP to HTTPS using Azure Functions and then process to Cumulocity. But not sure, whether YAML can be ingested to Event hub and cross proxy CoAP to HTTPS in Functions APP ? Could you please confirm  ?

Comment: If you willing to run a "compute vm" on your own, https://github.com/boaks/californium/tree/add_s3_proxy/demo-apps/cf-s3-proxy-server may be what helps. I don't use Azure, therefore only installs for AWS, DigitalOcean and ExoScale are available. But it should not be to hard to install it manually on Azure.

Comment: Thankyou Achim, will this work for CoAP over UDP. In market place I think similar one available in Azure as CoAP receiver which needs to be installed on IoT Edge device.

Comment: Californium is mainly used with CoAP over UDP. It's some time ago, when I tested a "cloud vm" at azure, but at that time it was working without issues, But the proxy only writes/reads data to S3, not to an Event Hub or something Azure IoT Core specific. So it may unfortunately be the wrong for you.

Comment: If Azure Iot Hub is used then why the client will require the cumulocity , is the question ?,As Cumulocity doesnt support CoAP , so client is asking to translate CoAP to HTTPS in Azure.